# Files owned by Docker userns-remap user end up owned by nobody inside the container

Tags: docker, linux-namespaces

I am messing around with Docker user namespace remapping: https://docs.docker.com/engine/security/userns-remap/

I have enabled Docker user namespace remapping by modifying `/etc/docker/daemon.json`. Content currently looks like this:

```
{
  "userns-remap": "default"
}
```

I have restarted the Docker daemon. The default `dockremap` user was created as promised by the docs:

```
user@host:~$ id dockremap
uid=125(dockremap) gid=134(dockremap) groups=134(dockremap)
```

There's also an entry in `/etc/subuid`:

`dockremap:165536:65536`

Now, I have a folder with a shared file that I wish to bind-mount inside a container to make it available for reading. On the host OS the file has the following owner and permission setup:

`-rwxrwx--- 1 dockremap dockremap 0 april  8 19:19 shared_file.txt`

The file should NOT be world-writable. My actual intention is to safely share a file with some secret information inside it between the host OS and a container.

The parent directory is world-writable if it makes any difference:

`drwxrwxrwx  3 dockremap dockremap 4,0K april  8 19:20 .`

I bind-mount this into an Alpine container like so:

`docker run --rm -it -w /work -v $(pwd)/shared_file.txt:/work/shared_file.txt remaptest ls -lah`

I now expect the file to be owned by `root` with UID 0 inside the container and thus be available for reading. Instead, it is owned by `nobody` and not readable by `root`:

`-rwxrwx---    1 nobody   nobody         0 Apr  8 16:19 shared_file.txt`

`nobody` inside the container has the following ids:

```
/work # id nobody
uid=65534(nobody) gid=65534(nobody) groups=65534(nobody)
```

Do I have wrong expectations about how user namespace remapping and bind-mount file system permissions work together or are there something wrong here? I have tested this out on two different PCs. One of them running Ubuntu and the other one running Mint.

I also tested with a `Ubuntu-based` container instead of an `Alpine-based` one, but the results were pretty much the same. I could of course modify the Dockerfile that is used to build the image, but I am under the impression that the way I'm doing this above should work.

The actual `Dockerfile` I want to use this with comes from a Docker Hub and I wouldn't want to mess with how it is set up.

Comment: I came across the exact same issue. Did you manage to solve this somehow?

Answer (score 2):

*Let me start off by saying that in my own **very limited** experience I have found user namespace mapping to be a particularly tough subject to understand, especially when using docker. I personally feel, like it's almost by design to have wrong expectations. But still it's a powerful tool.*

**What is happening?**

In your case, I'd try mounting `$(pwd)` into the container as `/work` (instead of just the file) and run a `touch /work/test.txt`. On your host you will see that this file is created by a user with uid `165536` whe you run `ls -lan $(pwd)`. This is as stated in your hosts `/etc/subuid` file, but I agree it's not necessarily what you'd expect.

**What can be done?**

To address this, I'd change or prepend the mapping in `/etc/subuid`. For example, you could add a line before `dockremap:165536:65536`, stating `dockremap:125:1`. Since the uid of `dockremap` on your host is `125` and you just want to map this one uid, this line should do the trick.

Now, if you do the `touch` test again with a new file, you will see that your file is owned by `125` (aka `dockremap`) on the host and by `0` (aka `root`) in the container.

**Further reading**

I can recommend this post: https://www.jujens.eu/posts/en/2017/Jul/02/docker-userns-remap/